# Failure to Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.AppRef

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-3.1, dotnet-cli

When I tried installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.AppRef` in my webapplication in .net core 3.1.

However, I get this error instead:

```
Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 3.1.3' has a package type 'DotnetPlatform' that is not supported by project 'xxxxxx'.             
NU1213 The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 3.1.3 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project.
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: This issue has been asked before on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25860)

Answer (score 7):

Acording to the [package description on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref):

> This package is an **internal implementation of the .NET Core SDK** and is **not** meant to be used as a normal PackageReference.

Comment: But how to add reference to that project then??!
I need to move one some code from Asp.Net Core app into class library - HOW CAN I DO THAT if it is impossible to create class library and add to it the same packages as specified in main Asp.Net Core app?! So, test case is simple: (1) in VS 2002 create new Asp.Net Core app (it suggest to use .NET 7.0), (2) write some middlewares there, (3) try to move out these middlewares into class library... THAT LOOKS IMPOSSIBLE with VS 2002 GUI!

Answer (score 4):

According to [1] the correct way to reference the ASP.NET Core application assemblies from .NET Core 3.0 on is by adding a FrameworkReference, e.g.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  ......

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework

Answer (score -1):

Just add this to your shared controller project csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
```

Have fun.

This package deprecated because .net developers took this package into the sdk.

If you are keeping controllers in a separate project, add this to the project references for using target frameworks controllers and attributes.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This package is deprecated. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/2.2.2?_src=template