# Reference ActionResult in a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a library with interfaces, and a new interface should map exceptions to `ActionResult`. But I struggle getting this type to my project.

IntelliSense offers to install the package `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`, but then I get a warning in the Solution Explorer:

> Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.9' was restored using
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework
> 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult) says this class is from the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref`, but [it's for internal use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872619/failure-to-install-microsoft-aspnetcore-appref).

I also tried using `IActionResult`. IntelliSense offers to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions`, but it was last updated in 2018, and now it's deprecated.

What's the proper way to reference `ActionResult`?

Comment: Have you tried changing the csproj: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`

Comment: Check out the duplicates. Try adding `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` to .csproj file.

Comment: @GuruStron it worked, thanks! You can post this as an answer if you like.

Comment: @DmitryFedorkov Was glad to help! I've closed the question as duplicate - but you are free to upvote answers (which contains this info) to the linked questions.